# Regex Python not matching, but does on regexpal

Tags: python, regex

I'm currently trying to match phrases like mexico 1 - 2 cameroon using regex, it matches when using regexpal to test the regex, but no match in Python using re.

My regex is:

```
    regex = '(mexico[\s]*\d[\s]*[-][\s]*\d[\s]*cameroon)|(mexico[\s]*\d[\s]*cameroon[\s]\d)|(mexico[\s]*\d[\s]*[-][\s]*cameroon[\s]*\d)|(cameroon[\s]*\d[\s]*[-][\s]*\d[\s]*mexico)|(cameroon[\s]*\d[\s]*mexico[\s]\d)|(cameroon[\s]*\d[\s]*[-][\s]*mexico[\s]*\d)'
```

and my test phrase:

```
testphrase = RT @remitouja: @TheJUMPsociety cameroon 1 - 1 mexico #winecup #WorldCup"
```

I successfully match in regexpalbut not python, but the testphrase doesn't. But the following matches in both:
 `cameroon 1 - 1 mexico #winecup #WorldCup`

Using

```
if re.match(regex, testtweet) is not None:
        print "Is true"
```

to test

Comment: Show your code please. I suspect you're using `re.match` while you should be using `re.search`.

Comment: You must use a raw string: `regex = r'(mexico...'`

Comment: Correct, I am using:if re.match(regex, testtweet) is not None:
  print "Is true"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search).

You are not matching because `re.match` by default anchors your regex at the start of the string, as if the regex you had was `^(mexico....` (etc):

```
if re.search(regex, testtweet) is not None:
    print "Is true"
```

Secondly, it's a good habit to raw your python regex strings my putting an `r` in front:

```
regex = r'(mexico[\s]*\d[\s]*[-][\s]*\d[\s]*cameroon)|(mexico[\s]*\d[\s]*cameroon[\s]\d)|(mexico[\s]*\d[\s]*[-][\s]*cameroon[\s]*\d)|(cameroon[\s]*\d[\s]*[-][\s]*\d[\s]*mexico)|(cameroon[\s]*\d[\s]*mexico[\s]\d)|(cameroon[\s]*\d[\s]*[-][\s]*mexico[\s]*\d)'
```

Next, you don't need to put `-` between square brackets, or any other character if it is alone. And having many groups might be a handful, so I believe that removing the capture groups should suffice:

```
regex = r'mexico\s*\d\s*-\s*\d\s*cameroon|mexico\s*\d\s*cameroon\s*\d|mexico\s*\d\s*-\s*cameroon\s*\d|cameroon\s*\d\s*-\s*\d\s*mexico|cameroon\s*\d\s*mexico\s\d|cameroon\s*\d\s*-\s*mexico\s*\d'
```

Comment: Perfect fixed it, feel a bit daft now!